# Edit G+ Sign in button text programmatically on Android

Tags: java, android, google-plus

I'm developing android app with G+ as SSO (Single sign on) functionality following this docs https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

In my case, I need to create sign in and sign out in single button. When the user signed in I need to change the button text into "Sign Out". But

```
SignInButton gPlusLoginButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btGplus);
// login implementation
gPlusLoginButton.setText("Sign Out");
```

But SignInButton has no `.setText` method.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a clever way of doing this that searches for the editable view within the object.

```
protected void setButtonText(SignInButton signInButton, String buttonText) {
    for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);

        // if the view is instance of TextView then change the text SignInButton
        if (v instanceof TextView) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            tv.setText(buttonText);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

So, to implement, just call:

```
SignInButton gPlusLoginButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btGplus);
// login implementation
setButtonText(gPlusLoginButton, "Sign Out");
```

Hat tip to http://www.pcsalt.com/android/change-text-of-google-plus-signinbutton-android/

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) signInButton.getChildAt(0);
textView.setText("Your Text");
```